# How to give a jar file classes it needs?

Tags: android, jar

## Goal

- In android app, I want to use cache for images downloaded from internet
- Found following project: `https://github.com/mttkay/ignition`
- Part of the project is ignition-support which contains classes for doing exactly what I need
- In the pom file, there is a dependency on guava collections (`guava-collections-r03.jar`)
- I *somehow* managed to build the jar file via Maven successfuly. (*Somehow* stands for *I'm lame regarding using Maven*.)

## Problem

- Added the generated jar file to my android app, used the `com.github.ignition.support.images.remote.RemoteImageLoader` class (with the parameter for using cache set to true)
- When I run the app, **I get following exception** `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.MapMaker`
- This class is part of the guava collections jar file
- It doesn't help when I add the `guava-collections-r03.jar` to my project

## So, ...

Any idea of how to get the class from the guava jar file visible in the ignition jar?

(Interesting is, that there was no error during creating the ignition jar file with the `mvn clean install`)

Comment: What Android sdk version do you use, r17? How do you build you Android project, via Maven? How do you add the guava-collections-r03.jar to your (Android) project, via pom.xml?

Comment: The app is for 2.3.3 (API level 10), the android project was created and managed via ADT in eclipse, only the ignition-support lib jar was built via Maven. Then I manually added the guava jar file to libs folder of my android app from the maven repo where it was downloaded to (when the ignition jar was built). I hoped that could help, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

See http://groups.google.com/group/ignition-users/browse_thread/thread/5e9f153f0482d653